# checking function with assert in c language

Tags: c, function, assert, strcmp

I need to write c program to compare two strings without using `strcmp()` and then in another funtion check whether it works with using `assert()`

```
int len_str(char str1[])
{
    // getting the length of the string
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; i++);
    return i;
}

int compare(char string_1[], char string_2[])
{
    //compare two character strings
    int s1, s2;
    for(int i = 0; i < len_str(string_1); i++)
    {
        s1 += string_1[i];
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < len_str(string_2); j++)
    {
        s2 += string_2[j];
    }
    return s1 - s2;
}

void test_compare(){
    //return a negative number if the first is less, zero if both are equal or positive if the second is greater.
    assert(compare("sa", "sand") < 0);
    assert(compare("sand", "sand") == 0);
    assert(compare("sand", "sa") > 0);
}
```

Can somebody explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't initialize `s1` or `s2`.  Your compiler should warn you about that.

Comment: @u__ oops sorry I should include that part of my code too.Just a minute

Comment: What issue do you have with the code? Compiler error, asserts firing incorrectly, etc?

Comment: Your `compare` is *not* comparing strings (but some "hash-code" of them). Strings need to be compared in [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order*). With [UTF-8 everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/), it is more complex. You could download the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and study its implementation of  `strcmp`

Answer (score 1):

in `compare` the code is essentially adding up all ascii equivalent of characters supplied in `string_1` and `string_2` and subtracting so technically

```
"sa" and "as" return as 0
"asdf" and "fdsa" return as 0
```

also `s1` and `s2` are uninitialized so that is even bigger problem in the first case. To start with do this

```
int s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
```

Comment: it actually worked after i did the s1 = 0, s2 = 0;

Comment: at least it does not give out error anymore

Comment: try comparing "sand" and "ands" ; they are not equal right ?

Comment: they are... I did not think about that. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: as @basile-starynkevitch pointed in the comment above  string comparisons are little complex than this read more about lexicographic ordering and ask another question when you feel stuck